# URL still contains subdirectory after primary domain's been redirected

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Could you tell me what I need to edit in this so that my URL doesn't contain the subdirectory it is in?

```
# Justhost.com 
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?espritministries.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main 
domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress2/
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main 
domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress2/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main 
domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, 
etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?espritministries.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress2/index.php [L]
```

I got this from just host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it's just a setting in settings > general. I changed the site URL and wordpress URL

Comment: Problem is, I can't login back.

Comment: Got it, I added these lines --> define('WP_HOME','http://espritministries.com'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://espritministries.com/wordpress2'); in wp-config